# Do IE has some limitations of lines, that upto where it can excute?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, internet-explorer

My code is working fine for firefox and chrome but not for IE, after debugging i reached to some conclusion, that code has included lot of jsp internally that i could see in console of about 8000 lines code in firefox actually  but in IE console it is showing upto an extent but not complete lines then breaks. If i ll remove some spaces from my JSP then it will take some more extra lines in IE console. Do IE has some limitations of lines that upto where it can excute ?

Answer (score 0):

IE does not have a lines-of-code limit... try using [F12] to open IE developer tools, then execute the code and see what errors pop up.

Comment: That particular error generally means something's wrong with your syntax, either a typo or a mistaken assumption (such as attempting to load a css file as a js library).  You didn't mention which version of IE, but 8,000 lines should not be an issue (generally speaking; there may be a corner case, depending on the design).  Since the error goes away when you reduce the lines, I would start by reviewing the removed lines little things that are easily overlooked, such as misplaced blocks, missing semicolons, etc.

Comment: Max, look at the entire Error Message... it should be telling almost exactly where to look.